# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow' how to fix this?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, theano

*i got this problem on anaconda 3 and i install keras and i want to use tensorflow with keras , and not theano okay and when i import keras got this error  can anybody help my with that *

```
    Using TensorFlow backend.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-c74e2bd4ca71> in <module>()
----> 1 import keras

C:\Users\LibnT\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py in <module>()
      1 from __future__ import absolute_import
      2 
----> 3 from . import activations
      4 from . import applications
      5 from . import backend

C:\Users\LibnT\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\activations.py in <module>()
      1 from __future__ import absolute_import
      2 import six
----> 3 from . import backend as K
      4 from .utils.generic_utils import deserialize_keras_object
      5 

C:\Users\LibnT\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py in <module>()
     62 elif _BACKEND == 'tensorflow':
     63     sys.stderr.write('Using TensorFlow backend.\n')
---> 64     from .tensorflow_backend import *
     65 else:
     66     raise ValueError('Unknown backend: ' + str(_BACKEND))

C:\Users\LibnT\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in <module>()
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf
      2 from tensorflow.python.training import moving_averages
      3 from tensorflow.python.ops import tensor_array_ops
      4 from tensorflow.python.ops import control_flow_ops
      5 from tensorflow.python.ops import functional_ops

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Comment: Did you install Tensorflow? You have to install it separately. https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup#anaconda_installation

Comment: yes i install tensorflow but i can't get why is not working with keras as backend !!!!

Comment: Looks like Tensorflow is not installed properly. Install only Tensorflow using `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow` or `pip install tensorflow`. Keras is inbuilt with Tensorflow. Use Keras libraries without installing. Thanks!